# If A is diagonalizable and if q(x) is a polynomial, show that q(a) is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

The title has the actual question in it.  If it is diagonalizable that means it would be similar to a diagonal matrix.   I have gotten that so far out of the hand out he has given us.   When I look up other things it mentions eigenvalues, and we haven't talked about those yet.  Any ideas on how to proof this.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is diagonalisable i.e there exists $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal. $PQ(A)P^{-1}$ is diagonal. To see this, remark that $PA^nP^{-1}=(PAP^{-1})^n$ so $PQ(A)P^{-1}=Q(PAP^{-!})$.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not obvious that the  polynomial in $A$ is diagonalizable by same  transformation as $A$ itself? ---  and that the diagonalized polynomial matrix has entries that the are the polynomials of the diagonals in $A$.